Is an independent OpenAPI client required for each endpoint (URL)?
TL;DR:
Essentially as the title, do I need to install an independent OpenAPI client for each endpoint URL?
Details:
I am using an OpenAPI generator to create Python clients with the purpose of receiving data from multiple end points. For example, the OpenAPI endpoint URLs could be called:
https://some-url.com/swagger/yaml/User.yaml
https://some-url.com/swagger/yaml/Data.yaml

If relevant, these endpoints are based on OpenAPI Specification (OAS) v3.1.
As far as I understand from the official OpenAPI guideline, I am supposed to take the following steps, per URL:

Generate an independent Python client
Install the client package within the virtual environment (via pip)
Read the data from that URL/endpoint

As I have two URLs, I am assigning a unique name to each package, so that they both can be installed within the same venv virtual environemt via:
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
    --input-spec https://some-url.com/swagger/yaml/User.yaml \
    --additional-properties packageName=openapi_user \
    --generator-name python \
    --output ./generated_openapi_user
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
    --input-spec https://some-url.com/swagger/yaml/Data.yaml \
    --additional-properties packageName=**openapi_data** \
    --generator-name python \
    --output ./generated_openapi_data

While this works, I feel that I am not doing this right, or as expected. Installing a package for each URL seems a bit much.
As I am new to OpenAPI, I would like to hear what is the best approach to do this.

I'm not sure if I understood the question: in this case each "URL" is an API description file I think? If each yaml file is an OpenAPI description (maybe each file describes the various API operations in one component of the system) you could combine them into one API description and generate a single package from that.
For example, with Redocly CLI, you can use the join command to combine multiple API descriptions. (Disclaimer: I used to work for Redocly, pretty sure there are alternative tools as well).
